# I had two of my answers deleted and I don't understand why.

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette

I had two of my answers deleted and I don't understand why. I left the second answer as deleted by the moderator as I am not going to go against the moderator, rather a reason why the answers were needed to be deleted so I can help the moderator not to waste his/her time deleting my answers.

Comment: btw @Arjang please don't sign off your posts with your name.

Comment: @Sathya : do you mean not to put my name in the post? Ok, will comply, just force of habit in usual emailing. Why is it different with the posts here? tx

Comment: Your posts are automatically signed off with your user card. Plus it's mentioned in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) - `Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already "signed" with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answers triggered the low quality answer mechanism. Super User and the whole Stack Exchange network expects **high quality** answers. Both answers were either one liners not providing any real detail, or alternatively they were discussions, and not actual answers to the question. There is a comment system in place for users with more then 50 reputation to ask further information, and the idea is that you spend enough time on the site to the earn the right to comment on other questions.

For the record, in your case, one of the answers where deleted by you, and not the system. Whenever the system deletes and answer, it will always state who deleted it, either the community user, or a moderator.

For more information on what is expected in answers please read the [Answer Advice](https://superuser.com/questions/answer-advice) page. All content can be reviewed by the community at the [Review](https://superuser.com/review) page, and it is most probably where most of the flags come from. Also Jon Skeet released a good article on answering technical questions [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).

The answer advice page is also triggered by low quality answers at times, if the user decides to skip the page and still post their answer, the Super User community reserves the right to remove those answers.

Comment: Agreed, I think redeleted an answer myself after realising it was not good enough. Thanks